# How to get registry values with java?

Tags: java, swing, registry

I need to get all folders from registry paths
**`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`** 
and
**`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`**
and to change the Displayname of the selected by user value to for example displayname1. 
Is that possible with java? never worked with registry before and dont wanna spoil something.
thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `java.util.prefs.Preferences`

`Preferences p = Preferences.userRoot();`
for user preferences and
`Preferences p = Preferences.systemRoot();`
for system preferences

and then accessing each path

```
if(p.nodeExists("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") {
    p = p.node("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");

}
```

Comment: will this list all subfolders of Uninstal? and how to change dispalyname when user select 1 of them?

Comment: I just dont wanna try it all myself w/o being sure that this wont break anything. i can write all code w/o blocks where to get data from registry and  change it if u want. its not a problem. its only i never worked with registry before.

Comment: You'll get a Preferences object where each node exists. So basically yes, if there are other nodes under Uninstall you'll get them. Then after that you can modify and retrieve whatever you want. Look at the methods of java.util.prefs.Preferences. Do you need to change node names? or preferences names?

Comment: i ll try to figure out how to do this. probably i need pref name for selected node

Comment: can u give me a link where to read about changing registry values  with preferences. found something but about saving user preferences only. nothing about registry changes so far

Comment: I don't know why this answer is selected as solution. It does not work.

Comment: @Ulises You can't access arbitrary keys with Preferences. This code doesn't work.